# How can I repeat processing routine in QGIS, to a batch of Landsat images?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, qgis-processing, landsat-8

I have a batch of about 50 landsat 8 geotiff scenes that I want to process in QGIS to compare them. Basically, I need to make simple band math and change color scales.

Is there a way to make something equivalent to an excel macro/vba, or other repetition solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do basic calculations with [gdal_calc.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html):

```
gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"
```

Not sure if it's possible with multiple bands etc.

With [gdaldem](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html) you can create scales by using the mode [color-relief](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_color_relief). Basically you create a text file for your color scales and then run `gdaldem` referring to that text file.

```
gdaldem color-relief imput.tif scale.txt output.tif
```

Comment: thanks! I am not very familiar with python but I will try to follow your clue and see if I can do it that way. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to know python to run this. gdal_calc.py just happens to be a python script.